# Why does ffmpeg generate vague videos?

Tags: ffmpeg

I used ffmpeg to make a video (test.mp4) from 1000 image files in CentOS 7 useing the following command:

`ffmpeg -i frame%04d.png -vcodec libx264 -r 10 -t 100 test.mp4`

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/sunyp/software/ffmpeg/ffmpeg-4.1.4/ffmpeg-4.1.4-install --enable-network --enable-protocols --enable-muxers --enable-shared --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --extra-cflags=-I/home/sunyp/software/x264/install/include --extra-ldflags=-L//home/sunyp/software/x264/install/lib
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, image2, from 'frame%04d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:39.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 640x480, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 2.2, 4:4:4, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] 264 - core 157 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=15 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=10 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 640x480, q=-1--1, 10 fps, 10240 tbn, 10 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=  162 fps=0.0 q=25.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate= 838.9kbits/frame=  315 fps=314 q=25.0 size=    2816kB time=00:00:25.30 bitrate= 911.8kbits/frame=  400 fps=285 q=-1.0 Lsize=    4421kB time=00:00:39.70 bitrate= 912.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=597 speed=28.3x    
video:4415kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.125100%
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] frame I:2     Avg QP:15.07  size: 25651
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] frame P:109   Avg QP:18.77  size: 18455
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] frame B:289   Avg QP:25.81  size:  8504
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] consecutive B-frames:  2.5%  2.5%  3.0% 92.0%
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] mb I  I16..4:  2.3% 74.7% 23.0%
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] mb P  I16..4:  1.7%  1.7%  4.2%  P16..4:  3.4%  7.0% 12.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:70.0%
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.4%  0.4%  B16..8:  8.6%  9.1%  8.3%  direct: 2.8%  skip:70.2%  L0:39.3% L1:29.7% BI:31.0%
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] 8x8 transform intra:34.9% inter:4.3%
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] coded y,u,v intra: 38.0% 26.4% 28.7% inter: 15.2% 3.1% 3.3%
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 68% 22% 10%  0%
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 20%  8% 70%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 17% 26%  5%  6%  7%  7%  6%  6%
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] ref P L0: 47.0% 12.6% 21.8% 18.6%
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] ref B L0: 85.8% 10.6%  3.6%
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] ref B L1: 95.4%  4.6%
[libx264 @ 0xf3b8c0] kb/s:904.10
```

When playing the video with mplayer, I find the video is very vague (Please see [test.mp4](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fpl3KOZl2Bv5y9hd5rwVff91IdU5oYm0/view?usp=sharing) and [a video snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PtI9j.png)) and in the terminal where mplayer is launched, there are many error information:

```
Starting playback...
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]gray chroma
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]error while decoding MB 9 11, bytestream 12958
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]concealing 800 DC, 800 AC, 800 MV errors in B frame
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]gray chroma
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]error while decoding MB 20 15, bytestream 4359
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]concealing 629 DC, 629 AC, 629 MV errors in B frame
Could not find matching colorspace - retrying with -vf scale...
Opening video filter: [scale]
Movie-Aspect is undefined - no prescaling applied.
[swscaler @ 0x7f53d2b45640]bicubic scaler, from yuv444p to yuv420p using MMXEXT
VO: [vdpau] 640x480 => 640x480 Planar YV12 
V:   0.2   3/  3 ??% ??% ??,?% 0 0                                              
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]concealing 437 DC, 437 AC, 437 MV errors in P frame
V:   0.4   5/  5 ??% ??% ??,?% 0 0                                              
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]left block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1 at 0 10
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]error while decoding MB 0 10, bytestream 14914
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]concealing 849 DC, 849 AC, 849 MV errors in P frame
V:   0.8   9/  9 14%  4%  0.0% 0 0                                              
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]Reference 5 >= 4
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]error while decoding MB 9 21, bytestream 1725
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]concealing 400 DC, 400 AC, 400 MV errors in P frame
V:   1.6  17/ 17 11%  3%  0.0% 0 0                                              
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]Reference 4 >= 4
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]error while decoding MB 25 9, bytestream 16009
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]concealing 864 DC, 864 AC, 864 MV errors in P frame
V:   2.0  21/ 21 11%  3%  0.0% 0 0                                              
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]Reference 4 >= 4
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]error while decoding MB 27 9, bytestream 14898
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]concealing 862 DC, 862 AC, 862 MV errors in P frame
V:   2.1  22/ 22 11%  3%  0.0% 0 0                                              
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]Reference 3 >= 3
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]error while decoding MB 32 12, bytestream 6095
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]concealing 737 DC, 737 AC, 737 MV errors in B frame
V:   2.4  25/ 25 11%  3%  0.0% 0 0                                              
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]Reference 5 >= 4
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]error while decoding MB 23 7, bytestream 17057
[h264 @ 0x7f53d268f880]concealing 946 DC, 946 AC, 946 MV errors in P frame
```

Do you know what's causing the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Please show the original log from creating the video. Also, the term “vague” is not really understandable in this context. I am sure it is a translation issue. Do you mean that the colors are not saturated enough, or look “dull”?

Comment: The original log can be find at the following link. If you can download the video at the link above, , you can understand the word "vague". https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JEsuWTnaYCHz5WDRXvXejkr1JvrODP_Y/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks. Next time please add the log to the question directly by [edit]ing it. I still don't understand the word “vague” in this context. Can you please try to find a different term that expresses what the problem is?

Comment: You are generating `yuv444p` video which may not be playable everywhere. Do you get the desired result if you add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` to the conversion?

Comment: I don't want yuv444p if it is not playable everywhere. Could you tell me how to make a playable video? And how to use "-pix_fmt yuv420p"? Just add to the command line of ffmpeg?

Comment: The "vague" means the objects in the image become distorted and covered by irregular blocks of colors

Comment: Switch to mpv. There were some changes made to libavcodec's h264 decoder earlier this year and it looks like mplayer's bundled decoder is older than that.

Comment: You add the option between the input specification and output file name, so after `-t 100`.

Comment: When compiling mpv (./waf configure), I get the error : "FFmpeg/Libav development files not found." I have actually installed ffmpeg and added the ffmpeg/lib (which contains  libavcodec.so.58) to my $LD_LIBRARY_PATH. What should I do?

Comment: After add the -pix_fmt yuv420p option to ffmpeg (ffmpeg -start_number 6 -i frame%04d.png -vcodec libx264 -r 10 -t 100 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4), the video generated seems improved a litter, but still ugly. The background is grey (which should be white) and the objects is still not clear and parts of it looks like being covered by the background color.  Is there other solutions?

Comment: @YepingSun I play video with vlc and it works fine, but there are warnings. 
1. Can you upload original images?
2. Can you try adding `-bf 0` option and see if it improves?
3. Can you try adding `-intra` option and see if it improves?